# How to declare a IQueryable variable to be built by groupby in switch statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query variable for example:

```
var q1 = from db in db.customers select db
```

I'm building on the query with some conditions:

```
switch(userInput)
{
  case "name" : {var q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.name); break;}
  case "age": {var q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.age); break;}
  case "date": {var q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.date); break;}
...etc
}
q3 = from q in q2 select q;
```

If I do this I can't access the q2 I declared in my switch statements and continue building my query with q3. However, if I declare outside the switch statement:

```
IQueryable q2;
switch(userInput)
{
  case "name" : q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.name); break;
  case "age": q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.age); break;
  case "date": q2 = q1.GroupBy(q=>q.date); break;
...etc
}

q3 = from q in q2 select q;
```

It will give me an error that says "IQueryable q2 does not contain a definition for 'select'."

I also tried to declare my q2 with a type but as you can see my switch statement may as for either string, int, or nullable date (DateTime?) type. How to declare a useable queryable variable for the switch statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming `q1` is also `IQueryable` then just `q1 = q1.GroupBy...`

Comment: Question is: what you are trying to do with query later?

Comment: You can't. C# is a language of types - what type would `q2` have to be? You could try `q2.Cast<object>()` but I don't think you can easily accomplish what you want across types.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, after the step q2, my q3 will be used to select a user defined variable to sum. Say I have two more fields called ‘savings’, and ‘checkings’. I will sum these fields based on the characteristics grouped in q2, and return either total savings or checkings or just count depend on what the user ask for.

Comment: To be effective in SQL generation, it should be fully dynamic (ExpressionTree building). It is not trivial task, bu there is library https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core and sample of GroupBy https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/master/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/EntitiesTests.GroupBy.cs#L162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those props seem easily representable as a string and the original prop is available in the grouping, so just use something like your second form (but it might make your life easier to declare the variable holding the return type as an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<...>>`) and group them by the `.ToString()` of age/date to give a consistent result, or perform the same `select` on each of them in the switch, to give a consistent result (and declare the return holder appropriately)